# Trying to Manipulate String in Java and keep getting ""boolean value"

Tags: java, string

I'm coding in Eclipse, so some of my error messages might be different.  I'm trying to print a message so if there is no character 'a' in String s3, then it will tell the user to try another line of code.  The if part of my statement isn't having a problem, but the else portion is.  I can't seem to figure out how to fix my statement, so if anyone is able to help, thank you!!

```
//print the index of the last occurrence of the character 'a' in string s3
if (s3.indexOf('a')>= 0 {
System.out.println("The first occurrence of the character 'a' in both strings is at index " + s3.indexOf('a'));
}
else (s3.indexOf('a') > 0 )
System.out.println("There is no occurrence of the character 'a' in either string.");
}
```

Comment: Start by adding a close-parenthesis on the first line, so the code will compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The if-then-else statement provides a secondary path of execution when the "if" expression evaluates to false. So, in the else clause you don't need a condition.

```
if (s3.indexOf('a')>= 0 {
    System.out.println("The first occurrence of the character 'a' in both strings is at index " + s3.indexOf('a'));
} else {
    System.out.println("There is no occurrence of the character 'a' in either string.");
}
```

And the opening brace was missing in the else clause.
For more information, you could read the [official java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your `else` is missing an `else if` for your second test. Which isn't valid (and the condition you've put there isn't reachable given the first `if` test). You could just use `else`. Something like

```
if (s3.indexOf('a')>= 0 {
    System.out.println("The first occurrence of the character 'a' "
            + "in both strings is at index " + s3.indexOf('a'));
} else {
    System.out.println("There is no occurrence of the character 'a' "
            + "in either string.");
}
```

**or** change

```
else (s3.indexOf('a') > 0)
```

to

```
else if (s3.indexOf('a') < 0)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use else if statement.

```
if(s3.indexOf('a')>= 0     {
    System.out.println("The first occurrence of the character 'a' in both strings is at index " + s3.indexOf('a'));
}
else if (s3.indexOf('a') < 0 )
    System.out.println("There is no occurrence of the character 'a' in either string.");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use else will be enough
The second else is unreachable as the first if contains the same condition